# Free abelian subgroups of SL(3,$\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: reference-request, group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-groups

Does SL(3,$\mathbb{Z}$) have any free abelian subgroup of rank > 2?

I want to find 3 $\times$ 3 integer matrices with determinant 1 such that the matrices are commutative, but there exists no other "relation" between the matrices.

Comment: There are upper untriangular subgroups that are free abelian of rank $2$.

Comment: More trivially, any non-torsion element would give a free abelian subgroup, but perhaps this case was implicitly too trivial for your purposes?

Comment: In any case, the answer to the question is trivially yes, so you should make the question more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't know that it was trivial. I want to find explicitly commutative matrices A, B and C and I want to make sure that A, B and C don't have any relation between them.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the answer.